# Angular material mat form field template parse error after upgrade

Tags: angularjs

I started using @angular/material 2.0.0 beta.**10** and the  worked fine for me.

Now I am trying to upgrade to beta.**12**.

The npm install succedded and I changed the import in the module 
from **Md**FormFieldModule to **Mat**FormFieldModule which also succedded.

The issue is I am trying now to change in the html from:

```
<md-form-field>
   <input mdInput placeholder="Name">
</md-form-field>
```

to:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Name">
</mat-form-field>
```

When I run it, I get error

**Error: (SystemJS) Template parse errors**

with no details.

Any idea why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, instaed of this import:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/typings/form-field"
```

I had to import only in the material level:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material"
```